# Does a shadowmap have to cover the whole scene?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shadows

My example is that I have a [sponza](https://www.google.se/search?q=sponza&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=1115&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIk77Dn4iDxwIVShUsCh0o_w95#imgrc=pFvbiURidwZNtM%3A) model and want the sun to shine through the roof as shown in the picture.
What happens if I set the shadowmap to only cover a section of a scene? In this example only cover the hole in the roof and set everything else to be in shadow.
My thought process is that limiting the shadowmap to only cover the hole in the roof would lead to a higher resolution in the shadowmap and thus better quality of the shadows.

What happens when I read outside the texture in the fragment shader? e.g:

```
float depthTextureValue = texture(shadowMap, shadowCoordinate.xy).x;
```

Whould the texture-method return 0? -1?

Comment: Those are two questions, not one. No, the shadow map does not need to cover the entire scene. The less it covers, the greater is its resolution. Ideally you want it to cover only the world that the camera can possibly see (so any shadow casters in the camera frustum). Cascading Shadow Maps and similar techniques actually use multiple shadow maps to cover the frustum with higher resolution nearer the camera, and less resolution far away from it. Then, yes, that sampling returns a value between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the texture's (or sampler's) [wrapping mode](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Edge_value_sampling), which is settable using the `glTexParamter*` functions for each axis using the constants `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_[STR]`.

The two most common modes are `GL_REPEAT`, which causes the texture to wrap around, or `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, which repeats the edges of the texture.

Comment: This is my setup

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
 glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

I know the difference between GL_REPEAT and GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE. But I don't think I understand textures and mipmaps well enough just yet. Maybe there is some good tutorials out there?

Comment: @Edvin: What's your question? You're setting the wrapping modes using `glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);` and `glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);`.

Comment: I'm sorry.. I'm so confused when it comes to textures and FBO's and all that.

I'm trying to figure out how to put shadows on everything outside the shadowmap. Since The shadowmap will only cover the hole in the roof from the sponza model, that is the only thing interesting to me since I know everything else will be in shadow. Can I set the texParameter to return 0 when I read outside of the texture or something like that?

Comment: I can feel that everything I write is just garbage.. I apologize. I haven't quite reached the level of understanding that I would like regarding textures, FBO's, viewports, texels and so on and so forth..